# Permission Denied on my raspberry pi transmission

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, raspberry-pi, transmission

I installed on my Raspberry pi 3 running on Debian the headless version of transmission:

```
sudo apt-get install transmission-daemon
```

After this I stopped the service and I modified the settings:

```
sudo service transmission-daemon stop
sudo nano /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

Beyond changing user and password I changed also the download directory:

```
...
"download-dir": "/home/pi/Desktop",
...
```

After this I rebooted the service

```
sudo service transmission-daemon start
```

Now if I try to download any file I obtain the following error:

```
Error: Permission denied (/home/pi/Desktop/ubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso)
```

I don't see what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Transmission daemon runs as the `debian-transmission` user. This user is (probably) not allowed to write to `/home/pi/Desktop`. You can verify this with `ls -ld /home/pi/Desktop` and interpreting the output.

Change the permissions/ownership on `/home/pi/Desktop` or let Transmission download to a file where it is allowed to store data.

You can give `debian-transmission` access to the folder with `chown` or `setfacl`. In case you're not inclined to do any research on that, the following will probably work:

```
$ setfacl -m u:debian-transmission:rwX /home/pi/Desktop
```

Comment: Ok, these are the permission:
`drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 giu  8 23:03 /home/pi/Desktop`
It's possible to allow debian-trasmission to write also on pi folders?

Comment: It is... See answer

Comment: Thank you, I'll try when I can access again to my raspberry

Comment: @Timmy, any updates? If this solves your problem, please mark it as such so other people know this could solve their issue.

Comment: I'm really sorry the raspberry is gone off and so I don't have anymore the ssh access, in a couple of week I'll be physically there.

Answer (score 0):

I was tearing my hair out with this problem, until [a related question on the dedicated Stack Exchange Raspberry Pi site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82151/transmission-daemon-stopped-working-owner-or-permission-issue) prompted me to examine **/var/log/daemon.log**

I used the excellent [PiMyLifeUp guide](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-transmission/) to set up my Pi for torrent downloads, but didn't *exactly* follow the recommendations when editing **/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json**. Specifically, since I'd left "**incomplete-dir-enabled**" set to **false**, it didn't seem unreasonable for me to change the "**incomplete-dir**" setting to "**(unused)**", to remind me that I didn't intend to use it.

So you can imagine my surprise, gentle reader, when I found references to **Couldn't create "(unused)": Permission denied** in **/var/log/daemon.log**.

I've just edited **settings.json** so that "**incomplete-dir**" points to the same folder as "**download-dir**", and everything works fine! Fortunately, I already knew I had to run **sudo systemctl stop transmission-daemon** before my edit, otherwise the daemon would have simply overwritten my changes when it eventually shut down (I tore an awful lot more hair out before discovering this yesterday! :)